# Composition of paths in two spaces

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I'm not sure how to compose paths in seemingly two different spaces.

Let there be two paths.  $a$, and $b$ both in $X$; so

$$a : X \rightarrow X$$

$$b : X \rightarrow X$$

I think I know how to do this the composition is

something like   $a \star b = \{ a(2x)$ for $ x \in  [0, 1/2] , b(2x -1)$ for $x \in  [1/2, 1] $.

How does this change when

$$a : X \rightarrow Y$$

$$b : Y \rightarrow Z$$

What does the composition look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got your definitions mixed up:

A path in a space $X$ is a continuous map $f \colon I \to X$ (not from $X \to X$), where $I = [0, 1]$ is the unit interval. Such a path $f$ has starting point $f(0)$ and ending point $f(1)$.

You do have the definition of path concatenation correct: if you have two paths $a, b$ in $X$ **such that $a$ ends at the point $b$ starts** (so $a(1) = b(0)$), then the concatenation $a \star b$ is defined by$$(a \star b)(x) = \begin{cases} a(2x) & x \in [0, \frac{1}{2}] \\ b(2x-1) & x \in [\frac{1}{2}, 1].\end{cases}$$
Note that this is well defined at $x = \frac{1}{2}$, because $a(2 \cdot \frac{1}{2}) = a(1) = b(0) = b(2\cdot\frac{1}{2} - 1).$

Note that we cannot even concatenate two paths in a single space $X$ unless their endpoints line up correctly. So, if you have two different spaces $Y, Z$, there is no way to concatenate paths in $Y$ and paths in $Z$ without any extra information (like embedding them in some common space or something like that).